# Posting a comment downloads any comments made since the page was refreshed but doesn't update the time since the answer was posted

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

This can result in a situation where you have comments indicated as being older than what they're commenting on.

I'm posting in synopsis form because FF's view selection source gave me something that the editor interpreted as source, not as HTML marked up text.  If it would be beneficial I do have a copy of the page source saved.

1 Answer

*[Contents of the answer]*

**answered 3 mins ago**

*[A comment made after I loaded the page]* - **8 mins ago**

*[My comment]* 0 secs ago